# Does a SOAP Envelope allows DOCTYPE?

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

I actually have a soap envelope as mentioned below. On running it through POSTMAN or SOAP UI, I get the desired result. However, on adding the DOCTYPE, it gives me **400 Bad Request**. Below is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE doc 
[<!ENTITY win SYSTEM \"file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/testdata2.txt\">]>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:koh="http://kohls.com/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <Process>
  <doc>&win;</doc>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <webEnvelope>                       
        <TraceEvents/>
        <Properties>
           <PropertyTO Name="Assembly" Value="IS.XS.Rf.Mls"/>
           <PropertyTO Name="Type" Value="IS.XS.Rf.Mls.MlsRequestMessage"/>
        </Properties>
        <Pipeline>MlsMessagePipeline</Pipeline>
        <TargetService>RfPriceChanges</TargetService>
        <TargetTransaction>GetClearanceTicketLocations</TargetTransaction>
     </webEnvelope>
  </Process>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If I remove the DOCTYPE and its supporting tag from the xml, it runs successfully with 200 status code. Also, as per the url: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171003/soap-message-must-not-contain-a-document-type-declarationdtd

it says that DOCTYPE is not supported by soap envelope anymore. Also I checked the SOAP Doc but didn't found anything that relates to DTD usage. Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The [WS-I Basic Profile](http://ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-2.0-2010-11-09.html) specifically denies DTDs in SOAP envelopes:

> 3.2.3 Disallowed Constructs
>
> XML DTDs and PIs may introduce security vulnerabilities, processing
>   overhead and semantic ambiguity when used in envelopes. As a result,
>   certain XML constructs are disallowed by section 5 of SOAP 1.2.
>
> Although published errata NE05 (see
>   http://www.w3.org/XML/xml-names-19990114-errata ) allows the namespace
>   declaration xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" to
>   appear, some older processors considered such a declaration to be an
>   error. These requirements ensure that conformant artifacts have the
>   broadest interoperability possible.
>
> R1008 An ENVELOPE MUST NOT contain a Document Type Declaration. CORE
>   TESTABLE BP1007
>
> R1009 An ENVELOPE MUST NOT contain Processing Instructions. CORE
>   TESTABLE BP1208
>
> R1033 An ENVELOPE MUST NOT contain the namespace declaration
>   xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace". CORE TESTABLE BP1033

If you need to, you can [check WS-I compliance](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/projects/verify/wsi.html) in soapUI and build it into your assertions.